# How to pass a list of values from the controller to a JavaScript function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need assistance with the below foreach loop as it only displays the last value in the list but I would like it to display all the values , what solution could I apply on this issue.

```
        foreach (var item in jsonDates)
        {
          //The Last Value:("2022-06-29")
            ViewData["Dates"] = item;          
        }
```

Full Controller code:

```
    public IActionResult Calendar()
    {
        var dateList = _context.Tasks.Select(x => x.DateAllTaskCompleted != null ? x.DateAllTaskCompleted.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null).ToList();
        List<string> jsonDates = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in dateList)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                jsonDates.Add(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item));
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in jsonDates)
        {
            ViewData["Dates"] = item;
        }


        return View();
    }
```

So basically I'm parsing the ViewData to a JS calendar , now within jsonDates I have a list of all the dates.

JavaScript in View:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,next'
        },

        events: [
            {
                title: 'Attention: Checklist',
                start: @Html.Raw(ViewData["Dates"]),
                color: 'red',
            },
        ],


    });
    calendar.render();
});
console.log(@Html.Raw(ViewData["Dates"]));</script>
```

Comment: we need more information. what type is `ViewData` ? and how do you display the items

Comment: You didn't say you're trying to pass a list of dates to a view. What you wrote only stores a single string to a ViewBag entry named `Dates`. At the very least you'd have to use  `ViewData["Dates"]=JsonSerializer.Serialize(dateList);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes yes I knew I was just storing it , just that I was having issues to pass all dates to the view , much appreciate the assistance.

Comment: You don't need to serialize in the controller either. You can store the date list and use `@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(ViewData.Dates))` in the view

Comment: Okay I will give that solution a go.